# Not able to Deploy the SSIS Project to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, ssis, projects

I have installed integration services without any issues but not able to deploy the SSIS projects to SQL Server, If I try to connect integration services using object explorer I can connect without any issues.

I have given the permissions to the users on Integration services using Dcomcnfg.exe.

Please help me to resolve the deploying issue at the earliest.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Are you deploying to a server with multiple instances of SQL Server installed? How are you deploying to the server? What is the error you receive when you attempt to deploy?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 and Nope i have only one instance and am trying to deploy on Default instacne. I am trying to Deploy using the Managment studio wizard in Integration services Catalogs and it says below Error :

Comment: Error:-TITLE: Failed to launch the wizard
------------------------------

To launch the Integration Services Deployment wizard, one of the components: Integration Services, 
Management Tools - Basic or Business Intelligence Development Studio has to be installed by the SQL Server 2012 Standard, 
Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation Edition. To install a component, run SQL Server Setup and select the component name.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

You do not have SQL Server Integration Services *Service* installed. Locate your installation media and walk through the install and select the Integration Services component.

You can verify installation was successful by shelling to the command prompt and typing `dtutil.exe`. Once it stops reporting this error message, the install is valid

> one of the components: Integration Services, Management Tools - Basic or Business Intelligence Development Studio has to be installed by the SQL Server 2012 Standard, Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation Edition. To install a component, run SQL Server Setup and select the component name

Comment: C:\Users\502189856>dtutil.exe
Microsoft (R) SQL Server SSIS Package Utilities
Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2012. All rights reserved.

At least one action (Copy, Delete, Dump, Encrypt, Exists, Move, Sign, FCreate, F
Delete, FRename, FExists, FDirectory) must be specified.

Comment: Is it Error are installed successfully and i even tried installing the Integration serivces using the installation wizard but it says already installed and it doesnt allow me to install.

Comment: That is what you wanted to see (it lists the available options) You should be good to go

Comment: I am getting the Abover message if i ttry for dtutil.exe